# How to push elements to vector after it is cleared?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, reverse, stdvector

I am given an array of `n` elements and an integer `K` is given. I have to print the *sub-array* of `K`  elements in reverse order.

I am storing the elements in a vector and increasing the count. Once the count equals `K`, print the vector in reverse order and clear all the elements of the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int t; // No of test cases
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        // Size of array and The size of each group
        int n, k;
        cin >> n >> k;
        int arr[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
        vector <int> my_nums;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            my_nums.push_back(arr[i]);
            count++;
            if (count == k)
            {
                for (auto it = my_nums.rbegin(); it != my_nums.rend(); ++it)
                {
                    cout << *it << " ";
                }
                //Clear all elements in vector
                my_nums.clear();
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
ex:
I/P:
1
8 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Expected O/P:
3 2 1 6 5 4 8 7

Actual O/P:
3 2 1
```

Comment: Do note that `int arr[n];` is a variable length array (VLA) and is not standard C++.  You can directly replace it with a vector like `std::vector<int> arr(n);` to have portable code.

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to reset the `count`. In addition to that, the `my_nums` vector should be cleared after printing the elements in it.

```
count++;
if (count == k)
{
    for (auto it = my_nums.rbegin(); it != my_nums.rend(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    my_nums.clear();  // moved to here
    count = 0;   // --> reset here
}
```

But what happens when the  `count < k` but `i >= n` ? That means you need to print the `my_nums` again after the for loop if `my_nums` is not empty, in order to get the complete result.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // above code
}

if (!my_nums.empty())
{
    for (auto it = my_nums.rbegin(); it != my_nums.rend(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
}
```

---

Also, note that followings:

- [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)
- [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)
- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set "count = 0" at the end on the outer loop.

Comment: Could you give a more complete example of how to adapt the code in question?